# Setting spring.config.location as a relative path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to use relative path in `spring.config.location` ?

I have the following structure in IntelliJ

```
|-dev.yml
|-src
  |-main
  |-java
    |-com.foo
      |-MySpringApp.java
```

and run it with

```
--spring.config.location=dev.yml
```

which doesn't work

The only thing that works is setting full path

```
--spring.config.location=/user/.../myApp/dev.yml
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strange no-one ever answered this.

I just worked it out myself by trial and error.

A relative path is always going to work because Java is running from some directory wherever and whenever you run it. Just a case of discovering what it is.

In my case with Win10, Java 1.8, IntelliJ 2018 and Spring Boot 2.0.2, running my app as a Spring Boot app in IntelliJ, my relative path is relative to the project root.

So for you, I would assume that it starts out the same way, using the project root. Since that is where your properties are, you need `.`, and then since it is a directory, you need to append a slash on the end:

```
--spring.config.location=./
```

Comment: `file://` can only deal with absolute paths, I had to use classpath. e.g. `classpath:./application.yaml` for it to work. Above did not work without prefixing with classpath. For docker compose, this worked: `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION: 'classpath:./application.yaml'`

Answer (score 0):

[Read this spring boot configuration chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

I don't know about relative paths, but you can use `classpath:dev.yml` if you put the dev.yml file in the classpath.

Comment: Doesn't this make me embed configuration file in the app? I don't want to do this

Comment: No. It makes you put the file on the runtimr classpath, which does not imply embedded with the war file.